# volttron multiple platform connection tutorial

Tags: python, volttron

Hi I am trying to go through this [tutorial](https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/develop/deploying-volttron/multi-platform/multi-platform-multi-bus.html#multi-platform-multi-bus) getting one data collector instance of Volttron (rasp pi) integrated to a volttron central instance (Ubuntu) on a LAN using ZMQ. But the rasp pi doesnt appear to be talking to the volttron central instance.

This is the configuration of the "central" instance on IP address `192.168.0.191`:

```
(volttron) (base) bartlino@bartlino-Latitude-E5530-non-vPro:~/Desktop/volttron$ vcfg

Your VOLTTRON_HOME currently set to: /home/bartlino/.volttron

Is this the volttron you are attempting to setup? [Y]:
What type of message bus (rmq/zmq)? [zmq]: zmq
What is the vip address? [tcp://192.168.0.191]:
What is the port for the vip address? [22916]:
Is this instance web enabled? [N]: Y
What is the protocol for this instance? [https]:
Web address set to: https://bartlino-latitude-e5530-non-vpro
What is the port for this instance? [8443]:

The following certificate and keyfile exists for web access over https:
/home/bartlino/.volttron/certificates/certs/master_web-server.crt
/home/bartlino/.volttron/certificates/private/master_web-server.pem

Do you want to use these certificates for the web server? [Y]:
Is this an instance of volttron central? [N]: Y
Configuring /home/bartlino/Desktop/volttron/services/core/VolttronCentral.
Installing volttron central.
['volttron', '-vv', '-l', '/home/bartlino/.volttron/volttron.cfg.log']
Should the agent autostart? [N]: Y
VC admin and password are set up using the admin web interface.
After starting VOLTTRON, please go to https://bartlino-latitude-e5530-non-vpro:8443/admin/login.html to complete the setup.
Will this instance be controlled by volttron central? [Y]:
Configuring /home/bartlino/Desktop/volttron/services/core/VolttronCentralPlatform.
What is the name of this instance? [bartlino]:
Volttron central address set to https://bartlino-latitude-e5530-non-vpro:8443
['volttron', '-vv', '-l', '/home/bartlino/.volttron/volttron.cfg.log']
Should the agent autostart? [N]: Y
Would you like to install a platform historian? [N]: Y
Configuring /home/bartlino/Desktop/volttron/services/core/SQLHistorian.
['volttron', '-vv', '-l', '/home/bartlino/.volttron/volttron.cfg.log']
Should the agent autostart? [N]: Y
Would you like to install a master driver? [N]:
Would you like to install a listener agent? [N]: Y
Configuring examples/ListenerAgent.
['volttron', '-vv', '-l', '/home/bartlino/.volttron/volttron.cfg.log']
Should the agent autostart? [N]: Y
Finished configuration!

You can now start the volttron instance.

If you need to change the instance configuration you can edit
the config file is at /home/bartlino/.volttron/config

(volttron) (base) bartlino@bartlino-Latitude-E5530-non-vPro:~/Desktop/volttron$
```

vctl status

```
(volttron) (base) bartlino@bartlino-Latitude-E5530-non-vPro:~/Desktop/volttron$ vctl start --tag vcp
(volttron) (base) bartlino@bartlino-Latitude-E5530-non-vPro:~/Desktop/volttron$ vctl status
  AGENT                    IDENTITY            TAG                STATUS          HEALTH
0 listeneragent-3.3        listeneragent-3.3_1 listener           running [9827]  GOOD
a master_driveragent-4.0   platform.driver     master_driver      running [9826]  GOOD
b sqlhistorianagent-3.7.0  platform.historian  platform_historian running [9825]  GOOD
c vcplatformagent-4.8      platform.agent      vcp                running [9824]  GOOD
d volttroncentralagent-5.2 volttron.central    vc                 running [9822]  GOOD
(volttron) (base) bartlino@bartlino-Latitude-E5530-non-vPro:~/Desktop/volttron$
```

The Rasp Pi on IP address `192.168.0.102`:

```
(volttron) pi@raspberrypi:~/volttron $ vcfg

Your VOLTTRON_HOME currently set to: /home/pi/.volttron

Is this the volttron you are attempting to setup? [Y]:
What type of message bus (rmq/zmq)? [zmq]:
What is the vip address? [tcp://192.168.0.102]: tcp://127.0.0.1
What is the port for the vip address? [22916]:
Is this instance web enabled? [N]:
Will this instance be controlled by volttron central? [Y]:
Configuring /home/pi/volttron/services/core/VolttronCentralPlatform.
What is the name of this instance? [raspberrypi]:
What is the hostname for volttron central? [https://bartlino-latitude-e5530-non-vpro]:
What is the port for volttron central? [8443]:
['volttron', '-vv', '-l', '/home/pi/.volttron/volttron.cfg.log']
Should the agent autostart? [N]:
Would you like to install a platform historian? [N]:
Would you like to install a master driver? [N]: Y
Configuring /home/pi/volttron/services/core/MasterDriverAgent.
['volttron', '-vv', '-l', '/home/pi/.volttron/volttron.cfg.log']
Would you like to install a fake device on the master driver? [N]:
Should the agent autostart? [N]:
Would you like to install a listener agent? [N]:
Finished configuration!

You can now start the volttron instance.

If you need to change the instance configuration you can edit
the config file is at /home/pi/.volttron/config
```

vctl status on the pi:

```
(volttron) pi@raspberrypi:~/volttron $ vctl status
   AGENT                   IDENTITY              TAG                STATUS          HEALTH
44 bacnet_proxyagent-0.5   platform.bacnet_proxy proxy              running [1581]  GOOD
f3 listeneragent-3.3       listeneragent-3.3_1   listener
13 master_driveragent-4.0  platform.driver       master_driver
4f sqlhistorianagent-3.7.0 platform.historian    platform_historian 0
79 vcplatformagent-4.8     platform.agent        vcp                running [1606]  GOOD
```

The tutorial is stating at this point on the "central" instance I should see ZMQ certificates to accept but I have none. Any tips greatly appreciated!
[image]

Comment: Im commenting my own Question but would anyone be able to give me a tip on the VIP address configurations that should be used on both the Pi and "Central" instance? I couldn't decipher that in the documentation

Comment: The VIP address is the address that is exposed for volttron instances to communicate https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/develop/introduction/definitions.html.  I will update the definition of terms to have that in there!  Please tell me the output you get from https://bartlino-latitude-e5530-non-vpro/discovery/ (well tell me that it has output).  Do this from the second box (vcp box) use curl -k or whatnot if necessary

Comment: Hi Craig thanks for the response. So if I have this correct, the VIP address configuration for the platform `vcfg` would be the same IP address of the device. Rasp pi `vcfg` VIP address would == Rasp pi IP address and the ubuntu central instance `vcfg` VIP address would == ubuntu box IP address.

Comment: Hi Craig, using a web browser on the ubuntu box of the "central" instance for  `bartlino-latitude-e5530-non-vpro/discovery` link you provided it will resort to a "Not Found". The web service `:8443/admin/pending_auth_reqs.html` seems to be working fine just no ZMQ keys to accept

Comment: `vctl status`

`a4 listeneragent-3.3 - running [2700]  GOOD`
`a6 master_driveragent-4.0 running [2699]  GOOD`
`2b sqlhistorianagent-3.7.0 running [2702]  GOOD`
`dd vcplatformagent-4.8 running [2697]  GOOD`
`87 volttroncentralagent-5.2 running [2701]  GOOD`

Comment: Note you need to have a slash on the end / sorry discovery/